# Why does SD not satisfy confidence interval value over multiple experiments, but mean and proportion do?

Tags: confidence-interval, chi-squared-test, standard-deviation

I have a population of 1000+ values of which I choose 300+ as my sample. I repeat this 3000 times.

I calculate for each experiment the estimated x-bar, SE(x-bar) as s/√n and using a normal distribution and a confidence value of (say) 90%, I calculate the interval.
Now I check whether the actual population mean lies within this interval in each experiment and it turns out that in ~90.7% cases of the 3000+, it does, as was expected.

Similar results are obtained for proportion (~89.5% times when 90% was chosen)

But when I do the same with Standard Deviation/Variance using a chi-square distribuion, with degrees of freedom (say) 299, and confidence level of 80%, using (n-1)s^2/chi-square, the actual value lies in the range for almost 98% of the experiments!

Calculations are done in excel so I'm stumped as to why the discrepancy is coming up. Is it because the population needs to be normally distributed for chi-square intervals to work?

Comment: Most likely your last observation is correct. While the sampling distribution for the mean begins to asymptotically converge to a normal distribution for relatively modest sample sizes, this sometimes does not happen with the sample variance when the underlying distribution is not normal unless the sample size is very large.